# Inner Join with one table and two fields

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Hello friends I have two tables

Users:
id,
name,
email

Incidence:
id_incidence,
id_users,
id_tech,
title, 
description

these are my two tables i want to get the name of the user and the tech name in the same query, all of them are in the users table i get to obtain the users name but how could i obtain the tech name in the same sql query? i have this

```
Select users.name,incidence.name,incidence.description from incidence inner join users on incidence.id_users = users.id
```

This work but i only obtain the user name with the title and description but i need to get also the tech name using incidence.id_tech = users.id

Comment: in which table tech_name field?

Comment: in users table all names are in this table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add one more instance of table `users` in `inner join`

```
SELECT
    A.name,
    incidence.name,
    incidence.description,
    B.name
FROM incidence 
INNER JOIN users A ON incidence.id_users = A.id
INNER JOIN users B ON incidence.id_tech = B.id;
```

**Note:** `B.name` is the name of the corresponding user referred by `incidence.id_tech` field.

Comment: Thanks this work perfect in the sql editor, i am trying now to run in codeigniter but i get an error Not unique table/alias: 'users' i don´t know it´s a copy and paste from the sql editor

Comment: The tables are properly aliased. Please double check everything.Since it works perfectly in the `sql editor` it should work in codeigniter too.

Comment: Executed in the sql editor and ok, copy and paste exactily in codeigniter and error, i think that codeigniter has other way to execute this or other sintax because the SQL setence is correct